# Why Solr-Magento connectivity is not working

Tags: php, magento, solr, lucene, jetty

I've got this problem that I can't solve. Partly because I can't explain it with the right terms. I'm new to this so sorry for this clumsy question.

Below you can see an overview of my goal.

I'm using Magento CE1.7.0.2 & Solr 4.6.0.

I'm using [Magentix/Solr](https://github.com/magentix/Solr) & its working fine only if the Solr files also in same server.

But now I have the Solr files in one Server & my Magento is in another Server it's not working.

If I re-index my magento, it's adds to the solr log file; but now it's not adding anything for re-indexing magento.

In Magentix extension i have the following data

```
 Enable Search  : Yes
 Enable Index   : Yes
 Host           : IP address of Solr file existing server
 Port           : 8983
 Path           : /solr
 Search limit   : 100
```

Why any thing wrong i did here ?

And i can able to see Solr Admin panel  **http:IP-ADDRESS-OF-SOLR:8983/solr** & Solr server is working fine only.

Its working for if solr files & magento is in same server

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

This may be a simple connectivity issue. From your Magento server try to 'ping' the Solr server from the command line:

```
wget http://IP-ADDRESS-OF-SOLR:8983/solr/admin/ping
```

That should give you a file called 'ping' containing:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
<lst name="responseHeader"><int name="status">0</int><int name="QTime">4</int><lst name="params"><str name="df">text</str><str name="echoParams">all</str><str name="rows">10</str><str name="echoParams">all</str><str name="q">solrpingquery</str></lst></lst><str name="status">OK</str>
</response>
```

If you cannot get that then try the ping from the solr server command line. If there is no ping then start solr. If there is a ping then check the firewall(s) between the boxes and open up 8983 for in/out traffic on both sides.

Comment: Thanks for the reply  its giving " HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK 
Length: unspecified [application/xml]
Saving to: `ping'
    [ <=> ] 380         --.-K/s   in 0s
2014-04-24 07:30:16 (39.0 MB/s) - `ping' saved [380]"

Comment: And have you done all the other basics, disable cache, login/logout, reindex? What does it say in the log, as in solr.log, system.log and eception.log?

Comment: Yeah... i did all basic things every thing is working as usual But in solr.log  only giving the following error"2014-04-25T04:18:06+00:00 ERR (3): '0' Status: Communication Error"

Comment: Internally it uses CURL to talk to Solr. Find `$responseBody = curl_exec($this->_curl);` in `magento/lib/Apache/Solr/HttpTransport/Curl.php` and add `Mage::log($this->curl);`, do a search and check the log file. Put together a simple php script with those CURL parameters and see what is going on.

Comment: its giving the following error  "ERR (3): Notice: Trying to get property of non-object  "

Comment: Okay, can you did into the curl code and set options to log what curl thinks it is doing? This answer here tells you how to add 'verbose' and log the requests/responses: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3757071/php-debugging-curl